# Blinking LEDs in reverse order

Tags: microcontroller, pic, c, microchip

The code below flashes some LEDs in order: pin 1, pin 2, pin 3, pin 4.

After this sequence has completed I would like to reverse direction and show pin 4, pin 3, pin 2, pin 1.

I wrote the code below but it's not working in reverse order.

What might be wrong?

```
#include <htc.h>

__CONFIG(1,OSCSDIS & HSPLL);
__CONFIG(2,BORDIS & PWRTDIS &WDTDIS);
__CONFIG(3,CCP2RC1);
__CONFIG(4,LVPDIS & STVREN);
__CONFIG(5,UNPROTECT);
__CONFIG(6,WRTEN);
__CONFIG(7,TRU);

#define _XTAL_FREQ   40000000


void delay_sec(unsigned char seconds)    // This function provides delay in terms of seconds
{
    unsigned char i,j;

    for(i=0;i<seconds;i++)
        for(j=0;j<100;j++)
            __delay_ms(10);
}
void led_display(char a)
{
    switch(a)
    {
        case 0: PORTB=0x01;PORTD=0x08;  break;
        case 1: PORTB=0x02;PORTD=0x04;  break;
        case 2: PORTB=0x04;PORTD=0x02;  break;
        case 3: PORTB=0x08;PORTD=0x01;  break;
    }
}

void main()
{
    TRISB=0x00;
    TRISD=0x00;
    char a,b;

    while(1)
    {
        led_display(a);

        a++;
        delay_sec(1);
        if(a==4)
        {
            a--;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You increment `a` every time and then you decrement it if `a == 4`. So `a` equals three in the beginning of you while-loop, then you increment it to four and decrement it, because it equals four. Now it is three again when you jump back to the start of loop.

Try something like:

```
bool directionForward == true;

while(1) {
    led_display(a);
    delay_sec(1);
    if(directionForward) {
        a++;
        if(a==4) directionForward = false;
    } else {
        a--;
        if(a==0) directionForward = true;
    }
}
```

And one other point: Try to avoid using this delay-function. Use a timer interrupt instead.

Comment: Your first line uses a comparison operator instead of an assignment operator, which is what I'm sure you meant. Also, I don't think htc has a `bool` type. I do think it has a `bit` type, though. Not sure if `true` and `false` are built-in.

Answer (score 2):

As your code currently stands, it will increment **a** until it reaches 4, then it will decrement it to 3 and then increment it back to 4.

That is, **led_display** will be called with the following arguments

```
0
1
2
3
3
3
....
```

If I understand you correctly, you would like it to successively increment from 0 until it reaches 3, and then decrement its way down to 0

The way I would implement that is by using a "direction variable", one way of doing so would look like this

```
TRISB=0x00;
TRISD=0x00;
char a=0, b, dir=1;


while(1)
{
    led_display(a);

    a+=dir;
    delay_sec(1);

    if(a==3)
    {
        dir=-1;
    }

    else

    if(a==0)
    {
        dir=1;
    }

}
```

*NOTE: this code is effectively the same as GER_Moki's, just the sequence and the operations are purposely verbose and closer to your original code for clarity*

Comment: Or, even shorter: if (a==3 || a==0) dir = -dir;

Comment: I don't like writing magic numbers... Add #define UP 1 and #define DOWN -1 to the code and use it (dir=UP; dir=DOWN).

Comment: Both completely correct comments. I consciously made the decision to keep it simple and aim it directly toward the questioner, who I feel may be not be a confident programmer; if my answer can address the question as simply as possible, then these two additions can only help along any beginning programmer toward mastery.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to what is presented in these other answers, I don't see where the variable *a* is ever initialized.  Since it is a local (on the stack) it is not be guaranteed to be 0 like it would be if it was a global variable.

The code currently reads:

```
char a,b;

while(1)
{
    led_display(a);
```

It should be something like:

```
char a,b;

a = 0;

while(1)
{
    led_display(a);
```

no matter what other changes are made.